# Freeze UI during backend calls Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a application, where during a first backend call to axios is still not finished, but the user can also make a second backend call or even multiple backend calls if he is fast enough to give so many inputs as he could.

I am wondering now how I can achieve a situation where after every single backend call, the User Interface will be frozen until that backend call is finished in Vuejs.

Any advices would be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your UI looks but first though that came is just to disable input (or button?) while the first request is still in progress.

You can also show some loader instead of input while the request is still in progress.

```
<form>
  <input />
  <button :disabled="loading" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**OR**

```
<form v-if="!loading">
  <input />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<loader-component v-else />
```

**Update:**
In case of drag/drop handler

I suppose you are doing that backend call in @change event handler. So as I suggested before add `loading` property to your component. Set it to `true` on first `change` event and after backend call is over set it to `false`.

```
eventHandler () {
  if (!this.loading) {
     this.loading = true
     // backend call
     this.loading = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! In my case, it is about dragging and dropping a folder. For example, I drop a folder A into a folder B, (this is a first backend call). And after that I try so fast as possible to drop another folder C into the folder B as well. 
And I saw that, the first backend call is still not finished, but the second backend call can also be triggered. It is harder than just for a Format. Is there anyway in Vue that I could prevent this ? Thank you !!!

Comment: You are welcome!) Glad my example helped!)